# Module 'torch' has no 'argmax' member (PylintE1101:no-member)

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I hope everybody is doing great. Please help me solving the below error.

Getting PylintE1101:no-member error

```
answer_start = torch.argmax(output.start_logits)
answer_end = torch.argmax(output.end_logits)
```

I got this error while trying to get the **tokens with highest start and end scores
**

Could anyone fix the error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is due to the pylint linter. It doesn't recognize `argmax` as a function of the `torch` module. Digging into the code, we find that it is because the actual implementation of `argmax` is in `torch._C`, a private module that is made public in the `__init__.py` file in `torch` root. However pylint seems to not look in this file to determine argmax as a member of torch. Your problem is similar to [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/701). Note that the problem arise not only for pytorch but also for other popular modules like numpy.

As suggested in [this github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/701) you have no other solutions that manually remove this wrong error in pylint settings in `pylint.rc` (create it with `pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc` if not already exists). Then, you can either:

- Writting this to prevent the error for torch only:

```
[TYPECHECK]
ignored-modules=torch
ignored-classes=torch
```

- Writting this to remove the no-member error for all modules (I personally did it):

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=no-member
```